# Draw vertical line on top of image

Tags: html, css

I've written a small Soundcloud player for my blog. I just added the possibility to skip in time when clicking inside the waveform. Now I'd like to draw a line at the current position in the track and a text indicating the curren position in time.

How would I draw this on top of my waveform (which is an `<img>`-tag) and which elements would I use?

[image]

Comment: Use an `<hr>` rotated 90º

Comment: Or a `<div>` that's 1 pixel wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. Absolutely positioned element (it doesn't really matter what element you choose - divs seem to be the best logical choice for me) to appear on top of the image, and easily scrollable. You denote the bar position using the `left` property. For your image, it goes between 48px and 358px. See here:

```js
function play() {
  document.getElementById('pos').className = 'end';
}
```

```css
#c {
  position: relative;
  }
#pos {
  height: 50px;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 48px;
  top: 1px;
  background: red;
  transition: left 5s linear;
}
#pos.end {
  left: 358px;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
  <div id="pos"></div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUNV8.png" />
</div>
<button onclick="play()">Play</button>
```

---

And combining it with your existing waveform listener is also easy:

```js
var pos = document.getElementById('pos');
var wave = document.getElementById('wave');

wave.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.offsetX < 48)
    return;
  pos.style.left = e.offsetX + 'px';
});
```

```css
#c {
  position: relative;
}
#pos {
  height: 50px;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 48px;
  top: 1px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
  <div id="pos"></div>
  <img id="wave" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUNV8.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: That's almost exactly how I did it myself in the meantime. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah, that's the approach... Small stuff like choosing an element, etc, doesn't really matter. You're welcome.

Comment: Yeah, I tried hr, div and span and figured as much. This is the finished thing (if you are interested) http://ali.dj/blog

Comment: Seems like the top margin is a couple of pixels too much on my Chrome/Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh noes, can you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: Sure: http://i.imgur.com/7LMd4a7.png Btw. why are you doing the 90-degree rotation? Can't you simply switch the width and height? (`width: 2px;  top: -5px;  height: 50px!important;`)

Comment: It looks like there's a lot more off. The Soundcloud data is missing alltogether. It should look like this http://i.imgur.com/sh4UnjQ.jpg?1 .
I started with a hr and had to rotate. Good catch!

Comment: Hmm, I thought you were still working on the actual implementation. Nothing happens when I click play... no errors in the console, no bad network calls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73499/discussion-between-hedge-and-shomz).